# Full month event calendar Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

i need a event calendar same as "http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/" for property rental project.

in "fullcalendar" we can only manage 1 month at a time but i want to manage more  then months at a time. eg i want to update event (actually not event, its place rent ) for 1 July to 15 Aug , 25 Aug to 10 Nov etc. 
so user can select any two dates and update related info.

or can i use "fullcanenar" for all months at a time ?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
             left: 'today',
             center: 'prev,title,next',
             right: 'month,basicDay'
         },......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1),

```
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-1)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            }}
```